Google Sheet Sequential Conditional formatting fails

I have 2 conditional formatting rules in Google sheets that looks for specific counties and applies formatting:
=REGEXMATCH($U2, "Brown|Calumet|Chippewa|Clark|Columbia|Dane|Dodge|Door|Dunn|Eau Claire|Fond du Lac|Green|Green Lake|Iowa|Jefferson|Kenosha|Kewaunee|Lake|Milwaukee|Oconto|Outagamie|Ozaukee|Pepin|Racine|Rock|Sauk|Shawano|Trempealeau|Walworth|Washington|Waukesha|Waupaca|Winnebago") -- Applies BOLD

=REGEXMATCH($U2, "Kewaunee|Vilas|Adams|Lincoln|Oconto|Juneau|Ashland|Portage|Marathon|Wood|Rock|Waushara|Langlade|Columbia|Richland|Forest|Burnett|Marquette|Crawford|Monroe|Manitowoc|Jefferson|Lafayette|St. Croix|Outagamie|Shawano|Jackson") -- Applies UNDERLINING

The range for both is the same.
I've highlighted the row of interest in blue in the screenshot. As you can see the bolding rule is applied but not the underlining. You can see elsewhere in the screenshot that both underlining and bolding work separately
Why not? How can I get both working on this row?

When first rule is true then it is applying back color and in first rule you do not have underline. Use underline in first rule. So, you apply both back color and underline in one rule. You do not need two rule here.

I ended up adding =AND( for both rules, because only 1 rule will be applied per row, so put the most restrictive first

=AND(REGEXMATCH($U2, "Brown|Calumet|Chippewa|Clark|Columbia|Dane|Dodge|Door|Dunn|Eau Claire|Fond du Lac|Green|Green Lake|Iowa|Jefferson|Kenosha|Kewaunee|Lake|Milwaukee|Oconto|Outagamie|Ozaukee|Pepin|Racine|Rock|Sauk|Shawano|Trempealeau|Walworth|Washington|Waukesha|Waupaca|Winnebago"), REGEXMATCH($U2, "Kewaunee|Vilas|Adams|Lincoln|Oconto|Juneau|Ashland|Portage|Marathon|Wood|Rock|Waushara|Langlade|Columbia|Richland|Forest|Burnett|Marquette|Crawford|Monroe|Manitowoc|Jefferson|Lafayette|St. Croix|Outagamie|Shawano|Jackson"))
